# Linux graphical GUI freezes

Tags: linux, graphics-card, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

Ok so I got this annoying problem that happens every so often where the entire screen freezes up, becomes a static image, can't do anything on it until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to console CLI screen, and back to the original when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to resume a working unfrozen screen again.

I expect this issue is a Nvidia problem, or the fault of X11 the way handles the GUI and graphics cards is just really annoying, because it will crash whatever application I may have open that's running on my Nvidia card. This is a laptop and it also has Intel HD Graphics 4000 series, so a dual hybrid graphics card thing going on. However it only runs on one card at a time due to the limitations of X11's way of handling two different graphic chipsets doesn't properly support or even have implemented a hybrid mode.

I use Linux Mint 17.1 (Cinnamon edition) 64-bit. I did a bit of looking around but I couldn't find anything similar to my problem, not even Google can come up with anything in the searches. By default the screen is on Pts/8 in LM.

I've checked and even updated the graphic drivers for Nvidia hoping it might fix the freezing issue, but it still persists. I doubt it's got anything to do with my settings for my Nvidia card.

Xorg vendor version is; 1.15.1 (11501000), Nvidia drivers are 349.16 *(latest as to my current knowledge)*. Nvidia card is GeForce GT 630M (2GB RAM)

The configuration of Nvidia card's image settings is set to High Performance. I wasn't too sure about some of the other options, but I have **Sync to VBlank** enabled, and **Allow Flipping** enabled for the OpenGL configurations, I may disable these if these might help the performance, but I doubt it'll help fix the freezing issue. For the Anti-aliasing settings it's got **Enable FXAA** enabled, although I have been considering disabling this as this disables triple buffering and other anti-aliasing methods.

I hope for the day when X11 gets a rewrite from the old 80's code so it supports dual-graphics cards properly. But I have been considering removing X11 altogether and replace it with something a little more user friendly like Wayland or some other that natively and supports hybrid graphic systems, even if it means to sacrifice compatibility with some applications and such that doesn't work with another windowing server.

Comment: I would like to add that I also have this issue, mint 17, nvidia, etc. It seems to mostly happen when I use the touchpad (which coincides when I'm on battery power). I have not found a fix, but I've tried different nvidia drivers.

Comment: @Jarmund - I don't believe I've had that kind of issue when using the trackpad, but then again I hardly use the trackpad much since I'm always using a tablet or mouse. I'm ever rarely on battery power due to that I'm always running my Nvidia card in High Performance mode.

Comment: It might be that being on battery power makes my system try to save power by using my intel somethingsomething that I normally never use, resulting in the same problem as you're seeing. For the record, I'm using the XFCE build.

Comment: Oh, another footnote: When I revert to console and back to xorg again, things usually resume fine afterwards, including any games. They just lock up the graphics but any sounds keep going as if everything is normal. A applications that are less forgiving might crash, but most times I can continue as if nothing happened.

Comment: The issue that sometimes happens when I'm playing games, the game crashes after I switch back, or the graphics start glitching all over the place in-game, and sometimes both.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing **nvidia-304** driver

[Check this link](http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_rebecca_xfce.php)

[image]

Comment: When I first installed Linux Mint 17.1 it was using 304 drivers, but they are obsolete to me and has quite a number of bugs in it, so I then updated it to 331.49 drivers, and was experiencing fewer bugs, but had the screen freeze glitch going on. Then I went on to go use 349.16 which I'm using now. There's just no way I'm going back to the old 304 drivers.

Comment: mm.. So you had the same freezing problem when using 304 drivers??

Comment: yeah pretty much. I think this might X11 related issue since it doesn't handle it so well and not a driver issue. I've been using Nvidia cards for a long time and they usually deliver quality and performance you expect them to run at with few bugs. Although Nvidia is still kinda new to making Linux drivers, they are improving greatly.